# React native Stack navigation how to use 'replace' in Stack action

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I want to use the replace method in Stack Actions in react navigation v2, but I'm not quite sure how I've looked at the specification here,
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-actions.html 
but I can't get it to work.

```
import { StackActions, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

const resetAction = StackActions.reset({

key:,
newKey:
routeName:

});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

I guess it's gotta be in some above format, but i'm not sure what has to go in to the parameters. Can anyone give me a working example?

Comment: Well, you could start by using `StackActions.replace` instead of `StackActions.reset` :)  It looks like, according to the docs, the only thing you need to supply is the new route name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you trying to reset or to replace?

- Use "Reset" when you want to erase all stack and create a new one. for example when deep linking to a certain path.
- Use "Replace" when you want to replace a specific element in the stack. for example you want to this.props.navigation.goBack() and navigate to a different route than where you came from

Comment: How can we use replace in Typescript? I get this ```Property 'replace' does not exist on type 'NavigationProp<Record<string, object | undefined>, string, NavigationState, {}, {}>'.ts(2339)```

Answer (score 1):

The useNavigation has a `replace` function under the hood but its not documented in the typings so you can type it yourself this way:

```js
const { navigate, replace } = useNavigation<
  NavigationProp<RootStackParamList> & {
    replace<RouteName extends keyof RootStackParamList>(
      screen: RouteName
    ): unknown
  }
>();
```

or a more elaborate version of it as a custom hook so you can avoid repeating this over and over:

```
// src/hooks/useNav.ts
import { useMemo } from "react";
import {
  NavigationAction,
  NavigationProp,
  NavigationState,
  StackActions,
  useNavigation,
} from "@react-navigation/native";

import { RootStackParamList } from "../navigation/routes";

const NAV_REPLACE_ACTION = "REPLACE";

interface UseNavAPI extends NavigationProp<RootStackParamList> {
  /**
   * Navigate by replace to a route in current navigation tree.
   *
   * @param name Name of the route to navigate to.
   * @param [params] Params object for the route.
   */
  replace<RouteName extends keyof RootStackParamList>(
    routeName: RouteName,
    params?: RootStackParamList[RouteName]
  ): void;
}

export function useNav(): UseNavAPI {
  const navigation = useNavigation<NavigationProp<RootStackParamList>>();
  return useMemo(
    () =>
      ({
        ...navigation,
        replace<RouteName extends keyof RootStackParamList>(
          routeName: RouteName,
          params?: RootStackParamList[RouteName]
        ): void {
          return navigation.dispatch(StackActions.replace(routeName, params));
        },
      } as UseNavAPI),
    [navigation]
  );
}
```

use it like:

```
import { VFC } from 'react';
import { useNav } from '<path>/useNav';

const MyComponent: VFC = () => {
  const { navigate, replace } = useNav();

  return (
    <>
      {/* ... */}
      <Pressable
        onPress={() => {
          replace('YourScreenName', {foo: 'bar'});
        }}
      >
        Replace
      </Pressable>
      <Pressable
        onPress={() => {
          navigate('YourScreenName', {foo: 'bar'});
        }}
      >
        Navigate
      </Pressable>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Sfili_81 hey ok i've updated my answer accordingly ;)